# Binding JSonArray to JQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I'm new to Jquery and JSon and trying to bind the JSON array result to JQGrid.

I can see the JSON result in Controller but not binding in the View.

Please help me on my code. Probably I was missing in the function in the view

This is the function raise when click on button to load results

```
function LoadOrganisationGrid() {

        var predifnedValue = $("#cmdOrgList").val();

        jQuery("#gridOrganisation").jqGrid({
            url: 'Home/GetOrganisationGridResults?predefinedMatchID=' + predifnedValue,
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            width: 1030,
            height: 275,
            colNames: ['Org_MID', 'P_MID', 'Candidate_Detail', 'CompanyName', 'StreetAddress', 'City', 'PostCode', 'Country', 'EmailDomain', 'VATNo', 'IsLinked', 'NotLinked'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Org_MatchCandidateID', index: 'Org_MatchCandidateID', width: 60 },
                { name: 'PredefinedMatchID', index: 'PredefinedMatchID', width: 50 },
                { name: 'Candidate_Detail', index: 'Candidate_Detail', width: 150 },
                { name: 'CompanyName', index: 'CompanyName', width: 100, align: "right" },
                { name: 'StreetAddress', index: 'StreetAddress', width: 150, align: "right" },
                { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 50, align: "right" },
                { name: 'PostCode', index: 'PostCode', width: 80, sortable: false },
                { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', width: 60, sortable: false },
                { name: 'EmailDomain', index: 'EmailDomain', width: 100, sortable: false },
                { name: 'VATNo', index: 'VATNo', width: 50, sortable: false },
                { name: 'Count_IsLinked', index: 'Count_IsLinked', width: 90, sortable: false },
                { name: 'Count_NotLinked', index: 'Count_NotLinked', width: 90, sortable: false }
            ],

            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager5',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Organisations Data"


        }).navGrid("#pager5", { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    }
```

And the controller code below

```
public JsonResult GetOrganisationGridResults(int predefinedMatchID)
    {
        var result = new SearchTypeModel
        {
            ListOrganisationType = GetOrgansiationList(SearchTypeService.GetOrganisationType(predefinedMatchID))
        };

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View code below

```
<table id="gridOrganisation" ></table>
      <div id="pager5"></div>
```

Comment: Please anybody can light on my query

Comment: Slash is missing befor `home` check once. url: '/Home/GetOrganisationGridResults?predefinedMatchID=' + predifnedValue,